# onScaleEnd received prematurely

Tags: android, scaling, zooming, pinchzoom

I am working on a feature in my app that does zoom-in and zoom-out. I have noticed that when I do zoom-in, then my app receives onScaleEnd() even though both my fingers are still on the screen. Because of this, my app behaves in an unexpected way. I have tested it on Nexus 5 Android emulator and Google pixel tablet. Note that when doing zoom-out, onScaleEnd() event is received as expected when I remove any one of the fingers from the screen.

Can anyone suggest why it is happening or is it a known android bug and how to workaround/fix it?

Answer (score 0):

According to android developers

**onScaleEnd** Responds to the end of a scale gesture. Reported by existing pointers going up. Once a scale has ended, **getFocusX()** and Responds to the end of a scale gesture. Reported by existing pointers going up. Once a scale has ended, getFocusX() and getFocusY() will return focal point of the pointers remaining on the screen. will return focal point of the pointers remaining on the screen.

Comment: I understand this but unfortunately it doesn't answer my question. In my case, when I am doing zoom-in and holding my finger on the screen for slightly longer time, then I am getting onScaleEnd() even though both fingers are on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The onTouch handler stops and calls onScaleEnd if the distance between your fingers is smaller than a predefined minimum.

See the code here: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.java;drc=68c65e58b4f4daf79c9ffab518a826a506799db2;l=347

The mMinSpan field is the minimum distance your fingers must move before the gesture is declared to be a scale (a pinch-zoom). That makes sense, but the gesture should not be aborted if the fingers get too close, by mistake.

As long as both fingers are still on screen, it's obvious the user is still zooming. This, in my opinion, is a bug in ScaleGestureDetector. It's still there 7 years later...

Comment: Please provide some code and not only a link. What of the link is broken in future?